# loop available dates, select one of them and fill the input box

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to fill in the input that is normally filled by a js code inside the html:

```
<input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control-input app_date validate" style="width: 260px;" id="app_date" name="app_date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" onchange="this.form.submit();showLoader();" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

js code got from html

```
import re

html = """
<script type="text/javascript">
var dt4  = '2019-03-07';
var blocked_dates = ["20-03-2019","01-01-1970","28-03-2019","29-03-2019","20-03-2019","01-01-1970","28-03-2019","29-03-2019"];
var available_dates = ["07-03-2019","08-03-2019","11-03-2019","12-03-2019","13-03-2019","14-03-2019","15-03-2019","18-03-2019","19-03-2019","21-03-2019","22-03-2019","25-03-2019","26-03-2019","27-03-2019"];
var fullCapicity_dates = [];
var offDates_dates = ["09-03-2019","10-03-2019","16-03-2019","17-03-2019","20-03-2019","23-03-2019","24-03-2019","28-03-2019","29-03-2019","30-03-2019","31-03-2019"];
var allowArray = [1];
</script>
"""
```

i successfully captured the available dates :

```
date_list = re.findall(r'var\s*available_dates\s*=\s*\[[^\]]+', html)
 if date_list:
    for av_date in re.findall(r"\"[0-9\-]+\"",date_list[0]) : 
       print(av_date.replace('"',''))
      Break
 else : print("no available dates")
```

output :

> 07-03-2019 08-03-2019 11-03-2019 12-03-2019 13-03-2019 14-03-2019
> 15-03-2019 18-03-2019 19-03-2019 21-03-2019 22-03-2019 25-03-2019
> 26-03-2019 27-03-2019

I don't know how to loop the availables dates , select one of them and fill the input and continue the py script. if no available dates keep refreshing the current page until available dates are found. i am confused is it a while loop, a while true or if ?

full js code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate()+1;
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    } 
    var today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
    function formatDate(rawDate) {
      var day = ("0" + rawDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
      var month = ("0" + (rawDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
      return (day)+ "-" + (month)+ "-" +rawDate.getFullYear() ;
    }       
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var dt1  = '2019-03-06';
        var checkService  = 'Normal';
        $('#dateOfBirth').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            endDate: new Date(dt1),
            startDate: '-100y',
            autoclose: true,
            startView: 2
        });
        $('#pptIssueDate').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            endDate: new Date(dt1),
            startDate: '-100y',
            autoclose: true,
            startView: 2
        });
        $('#pptExpiryDate').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            startDate: new Date(dt1),
            autoclose: true,
            startView: 2
        });
        var dt4  = '2019-03-07';
        var blocked_dates = ["20-03-2019","01-01-1970","28-03-2019","29-03-2019","20-03-2019","01-01-1970","28-03-2019","29-03-2019"];
        var available_dates = ["07-03-2019","08-03-2019","11-03-2019","12-03-2019","13-03-2019","14-03-2019","15-03-2019","18-03-2019","19-03-2019","21-03-2019","22-03-2019","25-03-2019","26-03-2019","27-03-2019"];
        var fullCapicity_dates = [];
        var offDates_dates = ["09-03-2019","10-03-2019","16-03-2019","17-03-2019","20-03-2019","23-03-2019","24-03-2019","28-03-2019","29-03-2019","30-03-2019","31-03-2019"];
        var allowArray = [1];
        if(checkService == 'Normal')
        {
            /*if((jQuery.inArray(2, allowArray)!='-1') || (jQuery.inArray(3, allowArray)!='-1')) 
            {
                var classFull = 'fullcapspecial';
                var tooltipTitle = '&nbsp;';
                var backDatetitle = 'Not Allowed';
            }else{
                var classFull = 'fullcap';
                var tooltipTitle = 'Slots Full';
                var backDatetitle = 'Not Allowed';
            }*/
            var classFull = 'fullcap';
            var tooltipTitle = 'Slots Full';
            var backDatetitle = 'Not Allowed';
        }else{
            var classFull = 'fullcap';
            var tooltipTitle = 'Slots Full';
            var backDatetitle = 'Not Allowed';
        }
        $('.app_date').datepicker({
            language: "en",
            Default: true,
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            startDate: new Date(dt4),
            endDate: '2019-03-31',
            autoclose: true,
            forceParse:true,
            startView: 0,
            beforeShowDay: function(date){
                   var formattedDate = formatDate(date);
                   if ($.inArray(formattedDate.toString(), blocked_dates) != -1){
                       return {
                          enabled : false,
                          classes: 'inactiveClass',
                          tooltip: 'Holiday'
                       };
                   }
                   if ($.inArray(formattedDate.toString(), available_dates) != -1){
                       return {
                          enabled : true,
                          classes: 'activeClass',
                          tooltip: 'Book'
                       };
                   }
 
                   if ($.inArray(formattedDate.toString(), fullCapicity_dates) != -1){
                       return {
                          enabled : false,
                          classes: classFull,
                          tooltip: tooltipTitle
                       };
                   }
                   if ($.inArray(formattedDate.toString(), offDates_dates) != -1){
                       return {
                          enabled : false,
                          classes: 'offday',
                          tooltip: 'Off Day'
                       };
                   }
                    return {
                      enabled : false,
                      tooltip: backDatetitle
                   };
                  return;
              }
        });
        /*====== CALL POP FOR PL/PT IN NORMAL CASE=======*/     
        if(checkService == 'Normal')
        {
            if((jQuery.inArray(2, allowArray)!='-1') || (jQuery.inArray(3, allowArray)!='-1')) 
            {
                /*$(document).on('click', '.fullcap,.fullcapspecial', function () {
                $(".datepicker").hide();
                $('.popupBG').show();
                $('#IDBodyPanel').show();
                });
                $(".popupCloseIcon").click(function() {
                $(".popupBG").hide();
                $("#IDBodyPanel").hide(); 
                });
 
                $('input[type=radio][name=serviceChange]').change(function() {
                if (this.value == 'Premium') {
                    $("#premiumService").prop('value', 'GO FOR PREMIUM');
                }
                else if (this.value == 'Prime') {
                    $("#premiumService").prop('value', 'GO FOR PRIME TIME');
                }
 
                });*/
            }
        }
        /*====== CALL POP FOR PL/PT IN NORMAL CASE=======*/
        var eventhandler = function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();      
        }
        if (checkService == 'Premium' || checkService == 'Prime') {
            $('input[name="vasId[]"]:checked').each(function() {
               $("#vasId"+this.value).bind('click', eventhandler);
            });
        }
 
        if (checkService != 'Premium')
        {
            $(document).on('click', '.chkbox', function () {
                if($(this).val() == 1)
                {
                    if($(this).is(":checked")){
                      //$("#vasId6").prop('checked', true);
                      //$("#vasId6").bind('click', eventhandler);
                    }else{
                      //$("#vasId6").prop('checked', false);    
                      //$("#vasId6").unbind('click', eventhandler);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you post the full code?

Comment: @soundwave Which code,  the js code containing the available dates or my python code ?

Comment: Please, also post full python code

Comment: @Alexey which part exactly do you need? I don't have the code on my smartphone

Comment: it is not clear how the data is passed to python, you are parsing the data using selenium?

Comment: at least post the url of the webpage, so that we can test by ourself

Comment: the web site requires a login an password unfortunately.  I am using selenium webdriver to automate the login process and detect  available dates in a datepicker.

Comment: @soundwave what do you think?

Comment: @Alexey what do you think?

Comment: you may just do selenium requests in while loop (maybe you need add some delay between requests) and break cycle when you get available date

Comment: @Alexey can you suggest a piece of code ?

Answer (score 0):

Just example, how you can use selenium

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=path_to_driver)
url = 'your_url'

while true:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    try:
        browser.get(url)
        page = browser.page_source
    except:
        print('In this iteration rise error, but we try again!')
        continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    input_data = soup.find('input', {'id':'app_date'}).text

    if check_available_dates(input_data): # check_available_dates - is function where you find dates via re and check this availables
        break
```

Comment: Beautifulsoup cannot parse javascript by the way.

Comment: You didn't get my point